# Rudin's PMA, 2.34

Tags: calculus, compactness

I'm still confused about this. There must be something that I've missed.

2.34 Compact subsets of metric spaces are closed.

2.32 $K$ is compact if every open cover of $K$ contains a finite subcover.

Now suppose $K$ is open in $X$. Then we get $K \subseteq K, K \subseteq \bigcup K$ (obviously).

But then $K$ is finitely covered by a series open sets (actually just one), so it is compact and yet we know that it is open, not closed.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Compact means that every open cover has a finite subcover, not that there is a finite open cover

Comment: A set can be open and closed at the same time

Comment: The fact that you found **ONE** open cover for your open set, such that there is a finite subcover (which is itself), does not mean that **EVERY** cover of $K$ has a subcover, so you have not proved that $K$ is compact... When you write "so it is compact" in the last line, that's not true

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's very helpful!

Comment: Let $K$ be the open interval $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R$.  $(0,1)$ is an open cover of $K$, and $(0,1)$ is a finite subcover of that.  But another open cover of $K$ has $(\frac13,1), (\frac14,\frac12), (\frac15,\frac13), (\frac16,\frac14),$ etc.  Is there a finite subcover of the latter open cover?  If not, then $K$ does not fulfill the definition of compact